# Javascript slider does not scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I've built a image slider based on the w3 html 5 demo. When I load the page, the first available image shows on the screen. When I click either the left or the right buttons the next image does not show as you can see here. Do you know how this issue can be resolved?

https://valuerent.co.uk/DLA/template/preview_property.php?property=135

code

```js
// Slideshows
var slideIndex = 1;
function plusDivs(n) {
slideIndex = slideIndex + n;
showDivs(slideIndex);
}
function showDivs(n) {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
showDivs(1);
```

```html
<div class="w3-content" style="position:relative">
  
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-opacity" src="property_images/houses1.jpg" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-opacity" src="property_images/houses2.jpg" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-opacity" src="property_images/houses3.jpg" style="width: 100%; display: block;">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-opacity" src="property_images/houses4.jpg" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
  <a class="w3-button w3-circle w3-hover-dark-grey" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="w3-button w3-circle w3-hover-dark-grey" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0;" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">❯</a>
</div>
```

Comment: remove/fix the code thats causing javascript errors on the page. Looks like on line 184 `mybtn.click();` is causing error because `var mybtn = document.getElementsByClassName("testbtn")[0];` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example which may help you:
if you are using jquery and want a dynamic example see this [example](https://codepen.io/Ferhad/pen/brzxgK)

```js
   var slideIndex = 0;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   function minusDivs() {
      if(slideIndex==0){
         slideIndex = x.length-1;
      }else{
        slideIndex--;
       }
     showimg(slideIndex);
   }
   
   function plusDivs(){
     if(slideIndex==x.length-1){
        slideIndex = 0;
     }else{
        slideIndex++;
     }
   showimg(slideIndex);
   }
  function showimg(n) {
     for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
     }
    x[n].style.display = "block";  console.log(x[n]);
  }
 showimg(slideIndex);
```

```html
<div class="w3-content" style="position:relative; width:500px; margin:auto">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-opacity" src="property_images/houses1.jpg" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-opacity" src="property_images/houses2.jpg" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-opacity" src="property_images/houses3.jpg" style="width: 100%; display: block;">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-opacity" src="property_images/houses4.jpg" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
  <a class="w3-button w3-circle w3-hover-dark-grey" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0;" onclick="minusDivs()">❮</a>
  <a class="w3-button w3-circle w3-hover-dark-grey" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0;" onclick="plusDivs()">❯</a>
</div>
```